# Can you run "fsck.ext2 -fycc /dev/mapper/truecrypt1" on an unmounted Truecrypt device?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, truecrypt, ubuntu-12.04, fsck

Can you run "fsck.ext2 -fycc /dev/mapper/truecrypt1"  on an unmounted Truecrypt device?

The "extra c" in the -fycc causes it to do a supposedly "non destructive"  read-write  (Similar to what Spinrite does).

However, since it's encrypted data I'm not sure if that somehow damages the data.

**This question was inspired by the following** (in addition to needing to check my drive of course):

> Filesystem check (fsck) a Truecrypt volume: http://www.chazco.co.uk/post.php?po=23
>   You can now run the filesystem check. Start a terminal and run the following command, replacing "/dev/mapper/truecryptX" with the value you made a note of:
>
> sudo fsck -C -f /dev/mapper/truecryptX

and

> [Bad blocks detected by fsck. SMART says disk is good](https://superuser.com/questions/462233/bad-blocks-detected-by-fsck-smart-says-disk-is-good) :
>   I suggest using the -c switch twice on fsck to force a read-write test
>   of the sectors. This invokes the badblocks program. It it accomplishes
>   roughly the same thing that GRC's SpinRite does. (SpinRite will work
>   on any linux formatted drive, btw.)
>
> Example fsck invocation: 
>   fsck.ext2 -fycc /dev/sdb1

Manual page for fsck.ext2 :

> -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do a read-only scan of the device in order  to  find  any
>                 bad  blocks.   If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block inode to prevent them from being allo‐
>                 cated to a file or directory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan will  be  done  using  a
>                 non-destructive read-write test.

Thank you in advance for any advice.